# how to create exceptions to JWT filter based on URLs

Tags: java, http, jwt, jjwt

I am working on JWT authentication.I want to bypass ( not allow to pass through jwt filter), the provided URLs. Below is the code snippet.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(bypassURLs)
                    .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfigProperties))
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);}
```

In the above code, I want the system Not to filter for bypassURLs.
If I am passing "/sayHello", then JWTAuthenticationFilter should not be applied to this while the URLs other than "/sayHello" must pass through the JWTAuthenticationFilter.

I have tried `http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/sayHello");` and some some regex but not succeded. Please help.

Comment: use `.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/sayHello").permitAll() `.

Comment: What I need is all the requests except "/sayHello" must be filtered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `permitAll` it means every authenticated user, however you disabled anonymous access so that won't work.

What you want is to ignore certain URLs for this override the `configure` method that takes `WebSecurity` object and `ignore` the pattern.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/signup");
}
```

And remove that line from the `HttpSecurity` part. This will tell Spring Security to ignore this URL and don't apply any filters to them.

Comment: This will not filter the specified url but how would I allow others to pass through filter. The URLs other than "/sayHello"

Comment: don't do anything ...filter will automatically apply on another URLs except  `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/signup")`

Comment: you just override the method `protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)` and add the filter ...that you have already added

Comment: just check other URLs is passing through filter or not ..let me know it's working or not..